# Is there a way to print multiple docx in a folder with difference printer properties?

Tags: python, pywin32, power-automate-desktop

Is there any method that allows me to print multiple Word documents that are in the same folder; 1) in a specific order and 2) with different printer properties?

For example, I have the following documents in a folder. I want to print them in that order with those specifications ten times, resulting in 10 packets that I can hand out to students.

1. Intro to Pysch   | single-sided, stapled, B/W
2. Syllabus         | double-sided, stapled, color
3. White Paper      | single-sided, color
4. Research Article | double-sided, stapled, B/W

A few methods that I am messing around with are [tag:python ] with win32, [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) and [powerautomate](/questions/tagged/powerautomate).

Any ideas or example would be very appriciated!! Thank you in advance.

I have primarily tried python using win32api and win32print but it only prints the first document. Also, I haven't even attempted to print multiple copies because I can't get it to print all the document in the folder.